# How to find upper and lower bounds to probabilities?

Tags: probability

Let $P(A) = 0.5$ and $P(B) = 0.4$

What are the largest/smallest possible values of $P(A ∪ B)$?

What are the largest and smallest possible values of $P(A ∩ B)$?

I am currently stuck on this question. I think it may have something to do with the inclusion exclusion but I'm not sure how to go about it for example:

$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$

so I can deduce

$P(A \cup B) \leq P(A)+P(B)=0.9$ but I am unsure how to find the lowest it can get and I have similar problems with the intersection.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What is the *largest* $\mathsf P(A\cap B)$ can be?

The union is smallest when the intersection is largest, and vice versa.

Comment: $P(A \cup B) \leq 0.9$?

Comment: I meant $P(A \cap B)$ above sorry.

Comment: Tip: Compare the size of an *intersection* to the size of the sets. @RyanS

Comment: I don't understand what you mean sorry.

Comment: Draw a Venn Diagram of two sets, one slightly larger than the other (areas 4 and 5, say).  What is the largest intersection you can draw with these sets? @RyanS

Comment: Put $B$ inside $A$

Comment: Right.  So, that gives you an upper bound on $\mathsf P(A\cap B)$. @RyanS

Comment: I get $P(A \cup B) \in [0.5,0.9]$ and $P(A \cap B) \in [0,0.5]$ sound good?

Comment: @RyanS Yes, though it is: $0.4$, not $0.5$.

Comment: Sorry for that twas a typo. Thanks!